# Why is my DateDiff returning a long negative number?

Tags: vbscript, automation

Very new to coding in general, especially to VB script.

I am attempting to start a timer on an action, and end it when a page loads. I then want to be told how many seconds that action took (the goal here is under twenty seconds).

When I run, it's returning a very long negative number.  -3733642190 seconds.

Here's the code.

```
'Choose the first record
PbWindow("w_mainframe").PbWindow("w_cash_detail").PbDataWindow("dw_search_main").SelectCell "#1","Contract_Party_Name"

PbWindow("w_mainframe").PbWindow("w_cash_detail").PbDataWindow("dw_search_main").ActivateCell "#1","Contract_Party_Name"

'start the timer
startTime = Now()

'Wait while the page load - up to 60 seconds.
While Not(PbWindow("w_mainframe").PbWindow("w_cash_detail").Exist(1)) and DateDiff("s", startTime, Now) <=60

Wait(1)
Wend

'If page did load, move on and test that the time was less than 20 seconds.

If PbWindow("w_mainframe").PbWindow("w_cash_detail").Exist Then
    Reporter.ReportEvent micPass, "Invoice Items Page", "Invoice Items page loads from ACD search results successfully"

    'stop the clock.
    endTime = Now()

End If

'Time Comparison


If ABS(DateDiff("s", startTime, endTime)) <=20 Then

Reporter.ReportEvent micPass, "ACD page opened in" & " " & DateDiff("s", startTime, endTime) & " " & "second(s)",  "The ACD opened this invoice in twenty seconds or less." 


else  Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "ACD page opened in" & " " & DateDiff("s", startTime, endTime) & " " & "second(s)", "The ACD took longer than twenty seconds to open a normal Invoice."
End IF
```

Comment: Look what happens when you run this. `WScript.Echo DateDiff("s", Now, Empty)` Does that help?

Comment: I'm getting an 'Expected end of statement' error when trying to save. I'm assuming I put it in the wrong place?

Reporter.ReportEvent micPass, "ACD page opened in" & " " & WScript.Echo DateDiff("s", Now, Empty) & " " & "second(s)",  "The ACD opened this invoice in twenty seconds or less."

Comment: You'd have to put that on its own line for it to work, but I was trying to illustrate that `endTime` is `Empty` - as in, it never gets set. Because it's only getting set inside the previous `If` statement, my assumption would be that the previous `If` statement is returning false, and `endTime` never gets set. Try moving it out of that `If` statement.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as an answer so others might see the cause and solution.

This would be the expected behavior if `startTime` is set but `endTime` is set to `Empty`.

The fix is to move this outside the `If` statement:

```
endTime = Now()
```